# Is it possible to restore a SQL Server 2012 Standard backup to a SQL Server 2012 Web Edition instance?

Tags: sql-server-2012, backup, restore

If I take a backup from a SQL Server 2012 Standard edition instance can I restore it to a SQL Server 2012 Web edition instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can restore the backup of Standard edition to web edition. Just make sure to use `restore database .. with move` if the file locations are different between the servers.

See the [comparison matrix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.110).aspx) for more details.